# What measures beyond those for general software, if any, should be taken when preparing a work PC for lunchtime or after-hour gaming?

Tags: hardening, software

In some companies (not the one I work for), there are certain groups of employees that have permission of management to play certain games on their office network after the work day has ended. This was mainly prevalent back in the days of local-only multiplayer and less so now, but some companies still allow this. In addition, some companies give certain employees permission to play during work hours, mainly security personnel during the graveyard shift or a quick match of FIFA or Quake during the lunch break. Some companies even buy a console to do so. For example, in my previous employment, the company installed an Xbox One which was used mainly to play FIFA.

If the company gives permission to do this, are there any measures that should be taken for this that go beyond those for installing software in general? Or are the threat models similar enough for this to not matter?

Comment: Note: I'm not sure whether games are sufficiently different from normal software for this question to be worth asking, but in case they are, I decided to just ask and see how it's received.

Comment: A game is just a normal application. What is of note is that in some jurisdictions the company has to be able to prove that they own enough copies of he game that is being played (e.a. that the software is legal). A console is easier to prove legality with.  Also remember to look for the 'phone home' functionality present in many games. And you should prefer DRM free games, as they interfere the least amount with the companies systems.

Comment: Since you mention it, is getting a console instead really out of the equation? To me, this is exactly where these are preferable to a proper PC. Do you want employees to play on their work PC, or on separate PCs dedicated to this?

Comment: @MadWard a console does not really lend itself well to multiplayer for many genres, especially more group-based games like team-based shooters. In addition, many games that are often played in multiplayer just play better with keyboard and mouse. Separate PCs might be an extra measure to be taken. My question mainly is about using company infrastructure for gaming, whether it's just the network, network and dedicated machines or network and just standard work equipment.

Comment: Unfortunately, games are really... badly designed, security-wise. An attacker could exploit any number of remote or local vulnerabilities in a gaming client to gain access to the user running the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate off network pc for gaming.
Or a video console off network and not a pc.

No gaming on corporate network.

Downloading games is risky, lots of backdoored bootleg copies of games that can put your whole company at risk.

Also keygens and license bypass tools are riddled with malware too.

Also game chat rooms are littered with social engineering , phishing links , etc that will lead to a breach.